# What are extensible elements in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

The WSDL document tells about extensibility elements, but what are these elements, why do we call them as extensible?

> In WSDL the term binding refers to the process associating protocol or
>   data format information with an abstract entity like a message,
>   operation, or portType. **WSDL allows elements representing a specific
>   technology (referred to here as extensibility elements) under various
>   elements defined by WSDL. These points of extensibility are typically
>   used to specify binding information for a particular protocol or
>   message format, but are not limited to such use. Extensibility
>   elements MUST use an XML namespace different from that of WSDL.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text segment you have posted is answering whatever you asked.

If you are still stuck I can suggest you to go through [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-3490/cnfg_wsdl-exten-elem_r/index.html) about it. Any explanation would be too big to post and painful to write down everything. This documentation is quite self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks Nik, The document says `Each binding components contain protocol-specific information, defined by WSDL Extensibility Elements`. So does it mean only those information that carry `protocol-specific` details are treated as `extensibility elements`? Is it just a term that is used to represent this or does it have more that what I am mentioned here?

Comment: Exactly.. it's protocol or message specific!(SOAP, HTTP or MIME etc) Extensible in the sense user has the option to define their own stuff.